# Can we display both time and date by using single button in android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I need help to display DATE & TIME value by using single button? Could any one help me to resolve this?

Comment: where do you want to display them ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Here are the steps:

- Create a button.
- Add an `OnClickListener()` to it.
- Inside the listener, Write code to display time and date.

Now you need to find out how to do each of those steps. These are the very basics of Android development. Go through the [developer training sessions](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) provided by Google to get yourself started on all things Android.

Here are some more resources that might help you:

- [Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)
- [Time & Date](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java_android_date-and-time/)

Welcome to StackOverflow and Android development! Good luck!